# Option for row_number and partition by in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, row-number

Here is my table `Student_Grade`:

```
id  StudentName subcode,Grade StdId
-----------------------------------
1   pinky         1     A   1
2   Archana       2     A   1
3   leena         1     A   1
4   leena         2     A   1
5   leena         3     B   1
6   Rupali        1     A   2
7   Megha         1     A   2
8   smita         1     A   1
```

Grade are from A to D.I want to show record only once when grade is same for same stid,does not matter what is subcode and studentname.For perticular subcode,appropriate studentname come when stid and grade specidy.If grade is different for same stid,show both record. Here I want to show

I applied `row_numer()`

Working properly in SQL Server 2005 not working in SQL Server 2000. How to do in 2000?

Query is:

```
SELECT 
    StdId, SubCode, Studentname, Grade, subjectname
FROM   
    (SELECT 
        StdId, SubCode, Studentname, Grade, 
        Subjects.subjectname as subjectname,
        Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cast(StdId as varchar) +' - '+ Grade ORDER BY SubCode desc,Studentname desc) rn
     FROM   
        Student_Grade
     INNER JOIN 
        Subjects ON Subjects.id = Student_Grade.SubCode) t
WHERE  
    rn = 1
```

Result :

```
stdid subcode Studentname Grade SubjectName
1       2     leena       A     Marathi
1       3    leena         B    Hindi
2      1     Rupali        A    English
```

Comment: There is no equivalent for `ROW_NUMBER()` in SQL Server 2000. How to do it? **Upgrade** to at least SQL Server 2005 ... (and even SQL Server 2005 isn't supported anymore by Microsoft - upgrade to something that's still supported!)

Comment: The alternative is to make temporary tables with identities/a forth running number, and use those temp tables in your procedure.

Comment: can u pls provide me syntax or modify above query

Comment: As a side note, you are aware that `PARTITION BY` can take more than one column/expression, aren't you? I can't see any reason why `StdId` and `Grade` have been mangled together versus just specifying both of them.

Comment: `SubjectName` is in result, but I cant tell from where it came. Provide accurate schema and data sample via SQLFiddle.com, I'll glad to help solve your issue.

Comment: @Swati have you solve this?